# Web: Display Opentok in Picture-in-Picture layout

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

I'm using Opentok.js, I want to display subscriber and publisher in Picture-in-Picture layout.It should be responsive and maintain ratio when I resize the window and How to get videos in full screen even if the video is in "320x240"?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a library which you might find useful. It handles layout of video elements for opentok and is configurable to lots of different settings.
https://github.com/aullman/opentok-layout-js

You can also find a very simple picture in picture layout example here https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Basic%20Video%20Chat

Comment: hey thanx!! now i'm using the 'opentok-layout-js' and displaying publisher and subscriber side by side. I even tried https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Basic%20Video%20Chat ,but this will not cover full screen of the device if the video resolution is 320*240!! and its not responsive!!